# Raspberry PiにSSHで接続するとアカウント認証に失敗します

Tags: raspberry-pi, ssh, raspbian

先日Raspberry Pi 3 Model Bを買いRaspbianをインストールしました。
自宅のパソコンからSSHで操作しようと思ったところ、SSH接続は確立しているのですがユーザー名とパスワードがあっているのに認証されませんでした。
ラズパイ自身からlocalhostで繋いだところ同じようにアカウントの認証に失敗しました。

解決方法が分からないため教えていただけると幸いです。

---

**追記 2018/11/13**
実際に行った詳細情報を以下に記載します

### ローカルIPアドレスの固定

/etc/dhcpcd.confに次の文を追記

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.112/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
```

### RaspberryPiのSSHを有効に設定

raspi-config → Interfacing Options → P2 SSH Enableに設定

### RaspberryPiにSSH接続

#### 自宅のPCから接続

```
>ssh -v root@192.168.1.112

OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.112[192.168.1.112] port 22.
debug1: Connecting established.
 ~省略~
root@198.1681.112's password:
debug1:Authentications that cancontinue: publickey, password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
```

#### RaspberryPi自身から接続

```
#ssh -v root@localhost
 ~省略~
root@localhost's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey, password
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

### rootのパスワード変更

```
#passwd
```

Comment: 何かエラーが出ているならそのメッセージを質問文にそのまま追記してみてください。(ログインが完了していないのなら接続は確立していない気がします)。localhostに対しての接続もできないのであれば、ユーザー名やパスワードが間違っているのではないでしょうか？可能であればsshdのログファイルを確認したり、デーモンの再起動を試してみてください。

Comment: > `ラズパイ自身からlocalhostで繋いだところ同じようにアカウントの認証に失敗しました。` となると、SSHが原因ではなくユーザーかパスワードが間違っているのではないでしょうか。ちなみにraspbianデフォルトのユーザー名は `pi` 、パスワードは `raspbian` です。

Comment: ユーザ名パスワードはRaspberryPiでは入れたため大丈夫だと思います。詳細情報を載せましたみていただけると幸いです。

Comment: localhost宛にSSHしたという意味だったんですね、失礼致しました

Comment: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`の`PermitRootLogin`は変更しましたか？Raspbianのデフォルトだと`PermitRootLogin without-password`になっており、公開鍵認証を利用した接続しかできないはずですが……

Comment: @PicoSushi さんのコメントの補足になりますが、sshではrootログインが禁止されていたりするので、`pi`ユーザーでの接続も試してみてください。必要に応じて`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`の内容を質問文に追記してもらうと具体的なアドバイスが付きやすいでしょう。英語版SOでの類似質問も参考までに - https://superuser.com/q/543626/435875

Comment: 解決しました。piのパスワードを変えていたのを完全に忘れていました。rootでも接続したかったのですが`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`の`#PermitRootLogin without-password`を`PermitRootLogin yes`にすることで可能になりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。piのパスワードを変えていたのを完全に忘れていました。rootでも接続したかったのですが`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`の`#PermitRootLogin without-password`を`PermitRootLogin yes`にすることで可能になりました。